# Cannot find input file

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program that asks the user for the name of a file, then opens the file, adds the sum of all the integers listed on the file, then writes that sum on an output file.

After writing my code and saving the `testfile1.txt` into the same folder as the program, the program keeps giving me the: *"could not access `testfile1`"* (message I output to notify myself that it is unable to open the `testfile1.txt`).

Here is what I have so far (skipped the lines with description blocks):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream inputFile;
    ofstream outputFile;

    string testfile1;
    string sum;

    int total = 0;
    int num;

    cout << "Please input name of file." << endl;
    cin >> testfile1;
    cin.get();

    inputFile.open(testfile1.c_str());

    if (inputFile.fail()) {
        inputFile.clear();
        cout << "could not access testfile1" << endl;
        return(1);
    }

    while (!inputFile.eof()) {
        inputFile >> num;
        total = total + num;
        inputFile.close();
    }

    outputFile.open(sum.c_str());
    outputFile << total << endl;
    outputFile.close();

    if (outputFile.fail()) {
        cout << "could not access file." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Question:

How can I make this program find and open the `testfile1.txt`?

### Note:

I am pretty sure that when prompted for the file name, I did not misspell.

Comment: When I get this error I first print the filename actually entered marked with "|" characters next to it. Many cases it is either a space or a newline in front of, or after, the name passed to open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are few remarks that will help you figure out the possible problem:

1.You could reduce some lines of code by attaching your streams to a file during definition, instead of defining them and then use `open`, like so:

```
ifstream inputFile(testfile1.c_str());
```

2.To check if a file is open (and handle if it couldn't):

```
 if (!inputFile) error ("Can't open input file: ", testfile1);
```

and:

```
 if (!outputFile) error ("Can't open output file: ", sum);
```

right after the definition.

3.All open files are implicitly closed at the end of the program (or a function that contains them), so there is no need to explicitly `close()` them.

4.To read the contents of the input file and sum them:

```
int sum = 0;
string line;
// read a line
while (getline(inputFile, line)) {
    stringstream ss(line);
    // assuming you are reading integers separated by white space
    int num  = 0;
    // extract each number on the line
    while (ss >> num) total += num;
    // reset line
    line.erase();
}
```

Note: test and modify your code according to your specific needs. A side note: you could probably omit: `cin.get();` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

use `getline (std::cin,name);`
for input name
and use proper function of ostream for reading and writing.

you'r getting input wrong at **line 21** and **line 22**